# Prevent SQL Injection in Livecode

Tags: sql-injection, livecode

I have a log-in form that is displayed via prompt (`ask`).
I have these scripts used to logged in the user.

```
ask "Please enter your username"
put it into username
ask "Please enter your password"
put it into password

revExecuteSQL tDatabaseID, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username=" &username& " AND Password="&password&"
```

When the user/attacker enters the `"` character in the form, the app shows that there is an error in the SQL scripts which this can make an user/attacker starts hacking.

How to protect the app from SQL injection in livecode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LiveCode does sanitisation and uses parameters in queries as described [here.](http://forums.livecode.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=11855&p=57040&hilit=sql%20parameter#p57040)

So, if you are building your query like this, LiveCode is not helping, and you do need to escape your own query:

```
get revDataFromQuery(tab, return, gConnectionID, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE '%" & theSearchString & "%'")
```

However, if you are doing your query like THIS, then LiveCode is already building a reasonably secure query for you:

```
get revDataFromQuery(tab, return, gConnectionID, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE :1", "theSearchString")
```

Comment: The script above is working. What's the purpose of the row delim and column delim?

Answer (score 1):

```
revExecuteSQL tDatabaseID, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username= ':1' AND Password=':2'", username, password
```

Do use parameter for the query construction, do not use string concatenation