# Block https://example.com/livewire/message/xyz external access

Tags: laravel, sql-injection, laravel-livewire, client-side-attacks

I have a web app that uses livewire, and in the past few weeks I've been having to deal with lots of SQL Injection attempts on the messages route used by Livewire. My question is: Is there a way to prevent this from happening, i have a firewall that was supposed to block this kind of stuff, but i dont think is beeing effective, so is there a way of blocking sql injection on the messages route used by livewire?

Comment: Do you want to block the attempts, or just make sure they are unsuccessful?

Comment: Have you seens similar questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61678797/preventing-sql-injection-for-a-raw-condition-in-laravel & 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019980/prevent-sql-injection-in-livecode and stuff like https://adevait.com/laravel/security-in-laravel & 
https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/sql-injection-prevention-laravel/

Comment: I dont want my website getting hacked, if i could block them it would be perfect, but assuring thath they will always be unssuccessfull would be great.

Comment: Have you tried cloudflare? They block a metric shitton of bad ips.

Comment: I use goCache intead of Cloudfare, but sometimes the attack passes the firewall

Comment: How are you tracking these SQL Injection attempts?

Comment: I use sentry for error monitoring and it logs when livewire detects invalid payload